# How to pass a Windows7 full path name?

Tags: c#

My coding in C# below :-

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filePathWithoutQuotes = "J:\\DataSource\\歌音楽\\Ver1\\夜霧の第二国道（カラオケ）フランク永井 (u6quC2KQNHw)(本人出演）.mp4";
    // case 1:
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Frank\\Downloads\\動画再生\\Qonoha\\qonoha20203\\qonoha\\Qonoha.exe",
        filePathWithoutQuotes);
    // case 2
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Users\\Frank\\Downloads\\動画再生\\Qonoha\\qonoha20203\\qonoha\\Qonoha.exe", 
       @"""J:\\DataSource\\歌音楽\\Ver1\\夜霧の第二国道（カラオケ）フランク永井 (u6quC2KQNHw)(本人出演）.mp4""");
}
```

Case 2: The Win7 fullpath name passed properly and the video file gets played and opened by the video player called Qonoha. This is just a control test to ensure the rests of the programming are properly done.

Case 1: The same video file did not pass properly as the video file failed to be played or opened.

Answer (score 0):

I see in case 2 you put the full name into quotes (`@"""J:\....mp4"""`), while in case 1 didn't (`aaa = "J:\....mp4"`). Though I doubt that solution may be so obvious, but have you tried `aaa = @"""J:\....mp4"""`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tool expects file path in quotes (which is quite common for cases where path contains spaces).

Your second case explicitly specifies quotes around the value: `@"""x"""` is string literal for x in quotes. The value for first case specifies just `"x"` and hence has no quotes.

Answer (score 0):

If your file name has white space, the `Process` will consider it as another command.

In command line if you pass command arguments directly without quotes `""`, it will consider it as another command if it contains white space.

In your case 1, exactly same happened.